# Sass - Setting variables with variables

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm looking to get a solid answer on whether it's possible to reference variables based on the value of another variable. This is possible in PHP (among others).

Example (in Sass):

I want to set the border-color to $green (or $blue, $yellow, etc), which are variables being included from a partial. I am looping through a list of color names like such:

```
$colors = green, yellow, blue; 

@each $c in $colors {
&.#{$c} {
    border-color: $#{$c};
    }
}
```

The above code (ideally) generates classes for .green, .yellow, and .blue, each with a border-color set to $green, $yellow or $blue, respectively.

(Obviously) the above code is not working, but is there another way of achieving this in Sass/Compass?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a duplicate of this thread: [using hash with scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354613/using-hash-with-scss) (which I've been watching/secretly pecking at for a few months now)

As Leo points out, you can try to work around this -- but PHP-style variable variables aren't something that the language currently supports.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I checked with @nex3, lead developer of Sass

In the google groups (mentioned below) discussion he actually said this kind of variable-interpolation is taking abstraction the wrong way and not what Sass intends to do. When I asked him, if he still holds true to that discussion, which was posted quite sometime back, here's what he had to say:

> yes, especially since we're adding maps in Sass 3.3, which will
>   support most use cases of variable interpolation anyway

Seems like Sass 3.3 will have a support for this via a feature called maps
Unable to find any documentation on that for now. If anyone can find links to it, please share

---

This kind of meta programming is not currently supported in Sass 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sass-lang/upr78cyrW1I