# SASS Mixin: how to pass a variable as parameter and then use it again as variable in mixin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, mixins

I have the following SASS code

```
.twitter-icon {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        @include icon($twitter);
        position: absolute;
    }
}

.facebook-icon {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        @include icon($facebook);
        position: absolute;
    }
}

.linkedin-icon {

...
```

I thought to optimize it with a SASS Mixin that generates different css classes and icon-fonts depending by passed parameters.

I started to write it as below, but I don't know how to replace native Bootstrap 2.3.2 `@include icon($twitter);` with the generic `@include icon($social-icon);` to have different CSS classes with different imported icons.

Actual solution works only for CSS selector `.#{$social-name}-icon`

```
@mixin socialIcons($social-name, $social-icon) {
    .#{$social-name}-icon {
        position: relative;

        &:before {
            @include icon($social-icon);
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
}

@include socialIcons(twitter, twitter-sign);
```

The problem is that I need that `$social-icon` could contain a variable (please, look at my original code) such as `$twitter`, `$facebook`, ...
and not a simple string.

Comment: I don't know if is necessary to modify also mixin call for example `@include socialIcons(twitter, $twitter);` or `@include socialIcons("twitter", "twitter");` but i'm opened to it

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  What you've already written looks like it does what you want.

Comment: You're right, I edited my question to better explain. Variables used in `@include icon(...);` are Boostrap default

Comment: Your question still makes no sense.  Variables don't contain other variables.  When you write `$foo: $bar`, the variable `$foo` contains whatever value `$bar` contained at that point in time, it doesn't contain a reference to the variable `$bar`.

Comment: So you're saying that replace all rules with a single mixin and many calls with different parameters is not possible in this case?  Please look at [this link in LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names). In LESS is possible to define variables with variable names, I thought that in SASS could be possible too.

Comment: I'm saying I have no idea what you're asking in your question because it makes no sense.  But if what you're asking is if Sass supports variable variables, the answer is no:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass

Comment: I found that calling mixin with `@include socialIconFont(twitter, $twitter);` accomplishes desired behaviour, but I can't write it as more complete answer due to "protection".