# Using SCSS variable inside a variable

Tags: css, loops, variables, sass

I want to use a SCSS loop as below:

```
@each $var in dark, purple, green, cyan, silver, white {

  .text-#{$var} {
    color: nth($color-, $var);
  }
  .btn-#{$var} {
    background-color: nth($color-, $var);
  }
}
```

in order to use the following variables:

```
$color-dark: #0D0E1E;
$color-purple: #333366;
$color-green: #33cc99;
$color-cyan: #00cccc;
$color-silver: #ccc;
$color-white: #fff;
```

but it is not working.
`$color-#{$var}` was not working as well. Can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating or referencing variables dynamically in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**nth** gets an item in a list. The first argument is the list, the 2nd is an index in the list. Also SASS thinks anything with a **$** is a variable, so **$color-** is a variable. You haven't defined **$color-** as a variable, and that's not your intended use.

[DOCS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method).

But you can get your desired result with a map...

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/cf174de8f40ba08619acd198b87cadeb)

```
$color-dark: #0D0E1E;
$color-purple: #333366;
$color-green: #33cc99;
$color-cyan: #00cccc;
$color-silver: #ccc;
$color-white: #fff;

$colors: (
  dark: $color-dark,
  purple: $color-purple,
  green: $color-green,
  cyan: $color-cyan,
  silver: $color-silver,
  white: $color-white
);

@each $name, $val in $colors {
  .text-#{$name} {
    color: $val;
  }

  .btn-#{$name} {
    background-color: $val;
  }
}
```