# Dynamic Variables from Sass Map

Tags: sass

I am looking for a way to generate variables dynamically from a sass map. So far I have looked into multiple examples, but all use a function like `weight(map-get($map, 'key'))` to get what is wanted. Instead I would like to generate the variable. For example

`font-weight:$__weight--thin;`

Notice the variable above. I would like to generate from a sass map like below:

```
//Font Weights
$__map--font-weights:(
    xthin:     100,
    thin:      200,
    light:     300,
    regular:   400,
    medium:    500,
    semibold:  600,
    bold:      700,
    xbold:     800,
    xxbold:    900
);
```

This map should spit out variables like:

```
$__weight--thin:  200;
$__weight--light: 300;
...
```

So far this is what I have:

```
@mixin makeWeights() {
  @each $key, $value in $__map--font-weights {
    $#{key}: $value
  }
}
```

Comment: Sass does not allow variables to be created or accessed dynamically.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass