# Concatenate defined variables with dynamic value of loop SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to loop some values ​​to concatenate them with some already set variables and just give it a color depth based on some sort of array.

These are my variables with the colors already defined

```
$brand-primary-surface-0: #fafafaff;
$brand-primary-surface-25: #f5f5f5ff;
$brand-primary-surface-50: #ebebebff;
$brand-primary-surface-75: #d8d8d8ff;
$brand-primary-surface-100: #c0c0c0ff;
$brand-primary-surface-200: #a1a1a1ff;
$brand-primary-surface-300: #767676ff;
$brand-primary-surface-400: #5c5c5cff;
$brand-primary-surface-600: #2e2e2eff;
$brand-primary-surface-700: #242424ff;
$brand-primary-surface-800: #1c1c1cff;
$brand-primary-surface-900: #151515ff;
```

This is the map that I want to cycle so that it takes a different value in each cycle

```
$deeps: 0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900;
```

Finally, I am cycling in this way to dynamically build the classes that I will inject into some components

```
@each $deep in $deeps {
    .brand-primary-surface-#{$deep} {
        background-color: $brand-primary-surface-#{$deep};
    }
}
```

The result I expected is like this

```
.brand-primary-surface-0 {
    background-color: #fafafaff;
}

.brand-primary-surface-25 {
    background-color: #f5f5f5ff;
}

.brand-primary-surface-50 {
    background-color: #ebebebff;
}
```

Instead I get this error

```
button
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/components/Button/Button.scss undefined
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
94 │ background-color: $brand-primary-surface-#{$deep};
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src\colors.scss 94:27 @import
  src\components\Button\Button.scss 1:9 root stylesheet
```

It seems you didn't like how I concatenated the variables. I'm a bit new to SCSS, what do you recommend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SCSS / SASS : How to create variables inside an each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250528/scss-sass-how-to-create-variables-inside-an-each-loop)

Answer (score 0):

To access a dynamic variable in SCSS is not possible.

Instead you should use a map:

```
$brand-primary-surface: (
    25: #f5f5f5ff,
    50: #ebebebff,
    75: #d8d8d8ff,
    100: #c0c0c0ff,
    200: #a1a1a1ff,
    300: #767676ff,
    400: #5c5c5cff,
    600: #2e2e2eff,
    700: #242424ff,
    800: #1c1c1cff,
    900: #151515ff
);

@each $key, $value in $brand-primary-surface {
    .brand-primary-surface-#{$key} {
        background-color: #{$value};
    }
}
```

> You can also use @each to iterate over every key/value pair in a map by writing it @each ,  in  { ... }. The key is assigned to the first variable name, and the element is assigned to the second. - [@each on sass-lang](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each/#with-maps)