# Showing error after incrementing variable as background inside @for scss

Tags: css, sass

Trying to increment background color value but getting error - 
//_defaults.scss

```
$module-bgColor1: #7476b5;
$module-bgColor2: #b7355f;
$module-bgColor3: #2e8bc5;
$module-bgColor4: #16417d;
```

and import this inside styles.scss file.
//styles.scss

```
@import 'defaults';
.alpha-list {
@for $i from 3 through 6 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      a {
        &.selected {
          &::before {
            background: $module-bgColor#{$i - 2};
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Showing Undefined variable.
What will be solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating or referencing variables dynamically in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it differently. Let me know if it's something you can do or not.

### First, I'll create a list with all the colors:

```
$module-bgColor : (#7476b5,
#b7355f,
#2e8bc5,
#16417d);
```

### Then, I'll iterate with a @for loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through length($module-bgColor) {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      a {
        &.selected {
          &::before {
            
            background: nth($module-bgColor, $i);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

### And all together:

```
$module-bgColor : (#7476b5,
#b7355f,
#2e8bc5,
#16417d);

.alpha-list {
@for $i from 1 through length($module-bgColor) {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      a {
        &.selected {
          &::before {
            background: nth($module-bgColor, $i);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks. i didn't know about 'length' property before but i still don''t understand why scss not increment each variables count.

Comment: In your code, sass is trying to compute `$module-bgColor` but it doesn't exist. It's not concatenating `$module-bgColor` and the number.