# concatenate SASS variable names using interpolation

Tags: sass

I have a hundreds of SASS variables in the following format:

```
$color-apples-bg: red;
$color-apples-fg; white;
$color-bananas-bg: yellow;
$color-bananas-fg: black;
$color-cherries-bg: burgundy;
$color-cherries-fg: white;
```

I'm trying to concatenate and interpolate the correct variable name like so:

```
$fruits: apples, bananas, cherries;

@each $name in $fruits {
  body.#{$name} {
    background-color: $color-#{$name}-bg;
    color: $color-#{$name}-fg;
  }
}
```

However, this results in an error on compile. Is it possible to do this some way?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @underscore_d I'm seeing undefined variable 'background-color: $color-#{name}-bg;'

Comment: Don't you need to write `#{$name}` in all cases, never `#{name}`? You did it right once but then wrong twice, AFAICS.

Comment: @underscore_d sorry, mistyped in my example - have updated.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact code and error, otherwise people waste their time reacting to typos occurring during transcription.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights it says `Error: Undefined variable. background-color: $color-#{$name}-bg;` and `$color-` is highlighted

Comment: I haven't tried concatenating Sass variables before but it looks like that could be why. Maybe try it with CSS variables and see if it works that way?

Comment: You can't do variable interpolation as of https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation

Comment: The best way right now is to use maps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating or referencing variables dynamically in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass)