# How to add $ sign in front of sass variables in @each loop

Tags: html, css, sass

```
$root-sizes:(
    'desktop': 20px,
    'mobile': 16px
);

@each $viewport,$size in $root-sizes{
    @media screen and (max-width: '$brk-'#{$viewport}){
        html{
            font-size: $size;
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
$brk-desktop
```

but it outputs `$brk- desktop` //with a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** possible to access [SCSS-variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) dynamically like that. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass) similar question out.

A quite simple workaround for this problem is to create an extra [`map`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) and access those values through your `each`-loop. Here's a working example:

```
$brk-sizes: (
  "desktop": 1200px,
  "mobile": 600px,
);

$root-sizes: (
  "desktop": 20px,
  "mobile": 16px,
);

@each $viewport, $size in $root-sizes {
  @media screen and (max-width: map-get($brk-sizes, $viewport)) {
    html {
      font-size: $size;
    }
  }
}
```

Since you have 2 [`maps`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) you could also create an extra [`function`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function) for that in order to make your code more readable and reasonable:

```
$brk-sizes: (
  "desktop": 1200px,
  "mobile": 600px,
);

$root-sizes: (
  "desktop": 20px,
  "mobile": 16px,
);

@function get-matching-viewport-size($viewport) {
  @return map-get($brk-sizes, $viewport);
}

@each $viewport, $size in $root-sizes {
  @media screen and (max-width: get-matching-viewport-size($viewport)) {
    html {
      font-size: $size;
    }
  }
}
```