# How to generate dynamic variable in SASS

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

How to generate dynamic variables in SASS?
I have array/list with colors:

```
$colors: (
  1: 'black',
  2: 'red',
  3: 'yellow'
);
```

And now, I also generate dynamic classes:

```
@each $i, $color in $colors {
  .bg-color-#{$i} {
    background-color: $color;
  }

  .text-color-#{$i} {
    color: $i;
  }
}
```

Now, I would like have just variables, like this:

```
$color-1: 'black';
$color-2: 'red';
// etc.
```

And in future using like this:

```
.some-class {
    color: $color-2;
}
```

So, my loop should be generate dynamic variables based on array/list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating or referencing variables dynamically in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass)

Comment: @dantheman No, a little other

Answer (score 0):

Fast Result:

```css
/* Colors */
$colors: 'black', 'red', 'yellow';
@each $color in $colors {
    .color-#{$color} {
        color: $color;
    }
}
```

or

```css
/* Step 1: styles.scss
/// ************************
/// @example
///  @include generate-color();
/// @return
///   .color-black { color: "black"; }
///   .color-red {color: "red"; }
///   .color-yellow {color: "yellow"; }
*/
@mixin generate-color() {
    $colors: 'black', 'red', 'yellow';
    @each $color in $colors {
        .color-#{$color} {
            color: $color;
        }
    }
}

/* Step 2: */
@include generate-color();

/* Step 3: Return ex. styles.css: */
.color-black {
  color: "black";
}

.color-red {
  color: "red";
}

.color-yellow {
  color: "yellow";
}
```

Comment: No tiene sentido generar las variables de forma dinamica, pero te recomiendo que aprendas a usar estructura de archivos, estare al tanto de la respuesta de otra persona.