# How to get sass variable content, coming dynamically from a string return value of a function?

Tags: function, sass

This is my initial context.

I receive from a third party a list of sass variables, and I can't change the shape of this data:

```
$green-primary-1: green;
$green-secondary-2: aqua;
$green-secondary-3: grey;
$red-primary-1: green;
$red-secondary-2: aqua;
$red-secondary-3: grey;
$blue-primary-1: green;
$blue-secondary-2: aqua;
$blue-secondary-3: grey;
// data represented here is fake
// ...
```

Then I've a function, that includes some logic and it returns the string of the name one of the previous sass variables, listed above:

```
@function get_var_name($param1, $param2) {
  // logic
  // ...

  @return "green-secondary-2";
}
```

And this function is used in some sass code to (try to) retrieve the content precisely of the specific named variable:

```
span {
  color: #{#{get_var_name('param1', 'param2')}};
}
```

and I'm expecting this output

```
span {
  color: aqua;
}
```

Instead I'm getting this:

```
span {
  color: green-secondary;
}
```

**Please, do not provide css variables approach as answer, or maps solution for my initial source of data or something different from the question context.**

My mandatory input is some sass variables.
My mandatory output is css property handled dynamically with these variables names.

Am I not seeing something obvious? Because I can't really make it work... And I feel it should be something stupid. Thanks anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating or referencing variables dynamically in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass)

Comment: The thing is, I do not have a map for source of variables. I've a list of `scss` variables. That is a requirement I can't change. Maybe what I'm trying to achieve is not possible with a function.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible, since the output is based on information written in build time, and it simply not possible, that is it

Comment: When you say you have a list of scss variables, do you mean a [sass list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists)?

Comment: No I mean "a bunch of", "some"

Comment: I think your question is missing some context because I can't understand why you can't use the variables directly or at the very least make a map with them as suggested by ThePeasantLife.

Comment: I tried to be more explicit. @Arkellys

Comment: Why not make a map of your color variables and then use `map-get($colors, get_var_name('param1', 'param2'))`?

Comment: Because I receive the list from third party, it can change with time, accordingly to some conventions naming, also implemented in the logic of that function. But no I can't make a map.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is possible then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, it seems *interpolation* is possible only in these scenarios:

- Selectors in style rules
- Property names in declarations
- Custom property values
- CSS at-rules
- @extends
- Plain CSS @imports
- Quoted or unquoted strings
- Special functions
- Plain CSS function names
- Loud comments

and apparently this is not the case of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it for you. No need for a function to return a sass variable

```
span { 
  color: $green-secondary;
}
```

**Edit - Option 1 - maps**

However, I don't know why you need the function? Can't you do something like this to achieve what you want. You could just make a map object on Sass with all variants

```
$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge((
  "hello":      #fff,
  "world":      #000
), $theme-colors);
```

Lets say I want to the hello value, I could use a map-get(variable_name, key)

```
map-get($theme-colors, "hello")
```

which would value from the key from that sass variable.

**Edit - Option 2 - Using root**

Another thing to note, you could do this via the :root and you can access a variable from the root in your css

```
span { 
  color: var(--hello);
}

:root {
  --hello: #fff
}
```

https://codepen.io/ciaabird/pen/PoKxZvz

Comment: my `function`, the rest of the code, is much more complex than this one, I can't follow this approach, but thanks for the attempt

Comment: I've just updated my comment, see if that helps anymore :)

Comment: I also edited the question, to give more context for a possible answer

Comment: I also don't have to do that via css variables, it has to be specifically done for `scss` variables

Comment: If the SCSS variable is in the root, you can access it anyway surely? I've quickly made this codepen for you, hope this helps clarify. I've put both of the solutions in the comment in there, you can just comment either or in to show them working :)

https://codepen.io/ciaabird/pen/PoKxZvz

Comment: Unluckily scenario is exactly represented in the question and can't be changed with css variables or root variables.