# Dynamically creating variable names in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, logic

I'm trying to dynamically create a variable, but that doesn't seem to be possible in SCSS:

```
$res-mat-xs: 0;
$res-mat-sm: 600px;
$res-mat-md: 960px;
$res-mat-lg: 1280px;
$res-mat-xl: 1920px;

@mixin media-min($var) {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $var) { @content; }
}

@mixin media-max($var) {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $var - 1px) { @content; }
}

@mixin media-from-to($var1, $var2) {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $var1) and (max-width: $var2 - 1px) { @content; }
}

$media: 'min', 'max', 'from-to';
$variants: 'very-small', 'small', 'default', 'large', 'very-large';
$breakpoints: 'xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl';

@each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
    .typo-style-#{$breakpoint}-#{$variants}-#{$breakpoint} {
        @include media-min($res-mat-#{$breakpoint}) {
            @include typo-style('default', 'important');
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, I am totally overwhelmed with the `from-to` (`$media`) and variants.

The class names for the `from-to` should look like this:

```
.typo-style-very-small-from-sm-to-md
.typo-style-large-from-sm-to-lg
```

How can I make these dynamic variables?

Comment: This post can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating or referencing variables dynamically in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass)