# SASS Generate variable name from @for loop

Tags: css, sass, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to create class names with certain properties from a @for loop. I'm not understanding if it's possible to achieve and what I'm doing wrong.

If it's of any help, I'm in a Nuxt3 project, using Vite. The error I get on `yarn dev` is

```
 ERROR  [sass] Undefined variable.                                                                                       11:03:32 AM
   ╷
87 │                 @include size($marketing-square#{$i}-size)
   │                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵

 ERROR  [sass] Undefined variable.                                                                                       10:57:10 AM
   ╷
90 │                 left: $marketing-square#{$i}-position
   │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  assets/style/_work-steps2.sass 90:23  @import
  assets/style/main.sass 9:9            root stylesheet
```

Here's my setup

**My variables:**

```
$desktop-size: $widescreen - (2 * $gap)

// SIZES
$marketing-square1-size: 136px
$marketing-square2-size: 80px
$marketing-square3-size: 120px
$marketing-square4-size: 174px
$marketing-square5-size: 220px
$marketing-square6-size: 70px
$marketing-square7-size: 130px

// POSITIONS
$marketing-square1-position: 0
$marketing-square2-position: $marketing-square1-size + 30px
$marketing-square3-position: $marketing-square2-position + $marketing-square2-size + 80px
$marketing-square4-position: $marketing-square3-position + $marketing-square3-size + 60px
$marketing-square5-position: $marketing-square4-position + $marketing-square4-size - 30px
$marketing-square6-position: $marketing-square5-position + $marketing-square5-size + 20px
$marketing-square7-position: $desktop-size - $marketing-square7-size
```

**The classes I'm trying to create:**

```
.gp__square
    bottom: 0
    left: 0
    position: absolute
    color: #898989
    white-space: nowrap
    border: 2px solid $black

    @for $i from 1 through 7
        &--#{$i}
            @include size($marketing-square#{$i}-size)
            left: $marketing-square#{$i}-position
```

Comment: You can not use a variable with a dynamic name. Use a map instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533432/creating-or-referencing-variables-dynamically-in-sass

Comment: @Duannx I get errors with that map in sass. is it for SCSS only?

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't use SASS. But SASS and SCSS have different syntax so you have to find out the right syntax for SASS