# Double interpolation (variable inside variable) in Sass

Tags: css, styles, compass-sass, sass

Is it possible to refer to a variable with another variable in Sass? I want to do something like this:

```
$gray = #ccc;
$white = #fff;

@each $color in gray, white {
    div_#{$color} {            // works fine
        color: #{$#{$color}};  // fails
    }
}
```

I tried all the variations I could think of to get the interpolation to work and no dice. Anyone know if it's possible? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354613/using-hash-with-scss

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. I fear it's the same now, though I'll keep it up just in case.

Comment: It is not possible. The link above is accurate.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that according to this post from Compass creator and Sass co-author Chris Eppstein, this ability is coming "in the future":

Maps - An new data type for storing an association between a key and a value. This will help us implement variable arguments for keyword-style arguments as well as address a very common request for "variable interpolation".

http://chriseppstein.github.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sass now has maps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps), so you can do:

```
$colors: (gray: gray, white: white);
```

then loop through it.

But you can't interpolate within interpolations.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but works! Nice addition to Sass, thx. BTW I'd do `$colors: (gray: #ccc, white: #fff)`